# Bayesian estimate of future life based on knowledge of prior distribution

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

This article, https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-be-less-wrong-5d6632a08f gives three examples of predicting the future life of something based on knowing its current life and the probability distribution of lifetimes. For example,

> Using Bayes’ law, we can again estimate where we expect an observation to end up, given where we see it today, and given the power-law prior. As it turns out, a power-law prior implies a multiplicative prediction rule: multiply the quantity observed so far by a constant factor, and this is the expected end result. For movie grosses, for instance, that multiple is around 1.4: given that a movie already made \$10 Million, it is likely that it will top out at $14 Million.

My question is how the math actually works. I'm familiar with Bayes' theorem and the power law distribution equations, I just want to know how to mathematically derive the fact that the expected total lifetime is a multiple of the current age.